# Performance in USING PERIODIC COMMIT n - Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm using the `LOAD CSV` command to import nodes and relationships in Neo4j. For better performance I'm using as well `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`, because I use large files to import (+/- 50 millions of records in each file).

I want to know if is better use `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000` or `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000` or a bigger number of records used in a bulk for performance.

The fatest way is put a big number or the oposite?

Ps: I have a lot of free RAM memory in the machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Big numbers will make the process faster. The reasoning is: a big number will results in less amount of commits. Consequently, a less amount of IO disk operations.

Example: With 1000 records and `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50` will results 20 write on disk operations (1000 records / 50). Changing to `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100` will results in 10 write on disk operations (1000 records / 100).

Comment: Do you about some formula to calculate the maximum number that you can use considering the available memory number? 

Thanks.

Comment: I searched the docs by something like this and do not found anything. Sorry. But remember you should configure the amount of RAM available to Neo4j before start the import process. Take a look in [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/load-csv-neo4j-quickly-and).

Comment: Yes, I know about the import process and works fine. I just want to improve the velocity of the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on something similar, my dataset contains some 700k data points.

I have seen that `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000` is taking more time to insert the data points in the database than `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000`.

So, in my case the smaller numbers are making my process faster and the **larger** the numbers are it throws an exception of *`not enough memory to perform current task`*

Comment: There's a balance to walk when choosing your batch size, between choosing a large enough value to allow fewer total commits, but not large enough to blow your heap. We tend to like batch sizes around 10k or so, but as all systems are different you'll need to test to see what works best with the memory available.